# How to parse SQL JSON string in C# in asp.net mvc web api?

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have created web api in asp.net mvc where I am calling `usp_JsonPract` this SP which is returning JSON string from DB, Now I am facing problem to convert this string on .net mvc web api.

My stored procedure code:

```
    Create proc [dbo].[usp_JsonPract]
    as
    BeginSelect  category title
        ,[data] = JSON_QUERY(
                    (
                    select din.dishId,din.dishName,din.dishPrice,din.dishImage, din.dishType,
                    JSON_QUERY(dishPriceAndSize, '$.dishPriceAndSize') AS dishPriceAndSize, 
                    JSON_QUERY(JAddOns, '$.addOns') AS addOns, 
                    din.includedEggs, din.dishDescription, din.rating, din.review,din.discount
                    from DishMaster din 
                    where din.category = dout.category 
                    --and dishId in ( 11, 12,13 , 7  )
                    for json path
                    ,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
                    )
                  )from DishMaster dout 
    group by category 
    for json path,without_array_wrapper
```

Stored procedure is returing JSON string that I want to pass to the client. I am using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstr);` to convert.

My C# code:

```
    public object SQLJSONPract()
    {
        string jsonstr = string.Empty;
        object o; 
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "usp_JsonPract";
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adp.Fill(ds);
            var d =  ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
            jsonstr = d.ToString();
            object a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstr);
            return (object)a;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Gives exception as below:

> "Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path `'userDetails[2].data[1].addOns[1].name'`, line 59, position 3."

Result sample JSON is like this:

```
{
"title": "Rice",
"data": [
    {
        "dishId": 11,
        "dishName": "stream rice",
        "dishPrice": 40.0,
        "dishImage": "streamrice.jpg",
        "dishType": "VEG",
        "dishPriceAndSize": [
            {
                "size": "Half",
                "price": 90
            },
            {
                "size": "Full",
                "price": 180
            }
        ],
        "addOns": [
            {
                "name": "Extrachess",
                "price": 25
            },
            {
                "name": "Chess",
                "price": 20
            }
        ],
        "includedEggs": false,
        "dishDescription": "stream rice is delicious in test",
        "rating": 4.5,
        "review": "GOOD",
        "discount": 20
    },
    {
        "dishId": 12,
        "dishName": "stream rice",
        "dishPrice": 40.0,
        "dishImage": "streamrice.jpg",
        "dishType": "VEG",
        "dishPriceAndSize": [
            {
                "size": "Half",
                "price": 90
            },
            {
                "size": "Full",
                "price": 180
            }
        ],
        "addOns": [
            {
                "name": "Extrachess",
                "price": 25
            },
            {
                "name": "Chess",
                "price": 20
            }
        ],
        "includedEggs": false,
        "dishDescription": "stream rice is delicious in test",
        "rating": 4.5,
        "review": "GOOD",
        "discount": 20
    },
    {
        "dishId": 13,
        "dishName": "stream rice",
        "dishPrice": 40.0,
        "dishImage": "streamrice.jpg",
        "dishType": "VEG",
        "dishPriceAndSize": [
            {
                "size": "Half",
                "price": 90
            },
            {
                "size": "Full",
                "price": 180
            }
        ],
        "addOns": [
            {
                "name": "Extrachess",
                "price": 25
            },
            {
                "name": "Chess",
                "price": 20
            }
        ],
        "includedEggs": false,
        "dishDescription": "stream rice is delicious in test",
        "rating": 4.5,
        "review": "GOOD",
        "discount": 20
    },
    {
        "dishId": 7,
        "dishName": "Chicken Biryani",
        "dishPrice": 160.0,
        "dishImage": "ChickenBiryani.jpg",
        "dishType": "NonVEG",
        "dishPriceAndSize": [
            {
                "size": "Half",
                "price": 90
            },
            {
                "size": "Full",
                "price": 180
            }
        ],
        "addOns": [
            {
                "name": "Extrachess",
                "price": 25
            },
            {
                "name": "Chess",
                "price": 20
            }
        ],
        "includedEggs": false,
        "dishDescription": "Special Chicken Biryani For Our Valued Guest",
        "rating": 4.5,
        "review": "GOOD",
        "discount": 20
    }
]}
```

> If any other suggestion for achieving this. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Is the resulting JSON longer than 2033 characters by any chance?

Comment: What is the exception *message*? You only posted the stack trace.

Comment: @Salman A , Yes it will go longer than 2033

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen , this is the exception message `"Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ,. Path '', line 13, position 169."` . If there is other way kindly sugges.

Comment: Well, for starters, you could avoid using ExecuteScalar. If you read [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar) you'll notice that it says: _The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the result set is empty. **Returns a maximum of 2033 characters.**_

Comment: @abuzar yes that was I was worried about. Nothing wrong with JSON, just a limitation of `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: `FOR JSON` has an issue that it will split large results. Wrap the whole thing in `SELECT (SELECT ... FOR JSON ...)` Also you are not giving Newtonsoft a type to deserialize, so you will just get a `JObject`

Comment: @AbuzarAnsari You have to replace images by text if you want to get a help.

Comment: Hi All,  Do you have any suggestion to do this work done. It is not mendetory to follow this exitisting procedure, I just need to return Result Like I shown above

Comment: @Charlieface, You are right,problem with sql code `FOR JSON`, can u plz correct my sql code and post to me. I am unable to solve. Thanks

Comment: I just told you: wrap the whole query like this `SELECT (SELECT category, title, [data] = .... FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)` although to be honest it's unclear why you are using JSON here anyway

Answer (score 0):

Make a file called `JsonPract.cs` and paste the following classes, in order to create several class that can be mapped to the json that you post in the question:

```
public class JsonPract
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}

public class DishPriceAndSize
{
    public string size { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
}

public class AddOn
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public int dishId { get; set; }
    public string dishName { get; set; }
    public double dishPrice { get; set; }
    public string dishImage { get; set; }
    public string dishType { get; set; }
    public List<DishPriceAndSize> dishPriceAndSize { get; set; }
    public List<AddOn> addOns { get; set; }
    public bool includedEggs { get; set; }
    public string dishDescription { get; set; }
    public double rating { get; set; }
    public string review { get; set; }
    public int discount { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize your object as:

```
JsonPract myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonPract>(myJsonResponse);
```

For example:

```
public JsonPract SQLJSONPract()
    {
        string jsonstr = string.Empty;
        object o; 
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "usp_JsonPract";
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adp.Fill(ds);
            var d =  ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
            jsonstr = d.ToString();
            JsonPract a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonPract>(jsonstr);
            return a;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks the above code is working for small json, Now I understood the problem is from SQL side. can you plz go through with my SQL code. When I am returning large no. of rows in JSON fromat from SP, then geting this exception `"Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ,. Path '', line 13, position 169."`

Comment: @AbuzarAnsari If the data is well, then the JSON is too long. You should considerer modify the structure of the query or use EntityFramework to do some several queries and then convert it to json on the C# layer, not on the database layer. Your approach works for a middle scale. I think you should open another question related to SQL (pasting mapping, your table, your queries, etc), because the main question that you do here, works fine with the answer: How to parse SQL JSON string in C# in asp.net mvc web api. It will get more attention from people who know about SQL in deep than C#